# List Rendering in React JS

Tags: reactjs

```
import React,{useState} from 'react'
import App from './App'
const AppList = ()=>{
    const [arr,addElement] = useState([1])
    const handleClick = ()=>{
        arr.push(1)
        addElement(arr)
    }
    return(
       <>
        {
            arr.map((elements)=>{
                return <h1>{elements}</h1>
            })
        }   
        <button onClick={handleClick}>add</button>
       </>
    )
}
export default AppList
```

I tried to add elements and render. the items are getting added in array but its not getting rendered in browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React is checking state updates by reference, since you provide the same array reference the component is not going to re-render.

Instead, make an immutable update

```js
const AppList = () => {
  const [arr, addElement] = useState([1])

  const handleClick = () => {
    addElement(prevState => [...prevState, 1])
  }

  return (
    <>
      {arr.map(element => (
        <h1>{element}</h1>
      ))}
      <button onClick={handleClick}>add</button>
    </>
  )
}
```

You also need to provide a unique key when rendering arrays, but don't use index as key since it can cause problems when adding and removing items from the array. You don't have anything unique here so you will need to think of a way of solving it. You can find more info about it [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html)

Answer (score 0):

to rerender somthing in React you need to change the state,
the best way to do it is to pass NEW array to the state, Thats why
you have the setState method.
So, you just need:

```js
import React,{useState} from 'react'
import App from './App'
const AppList = ()=>{
    const [arr,setArray] = useState([1])
    const handleClick = ()=>{
        let newArr = [...arr,1]
        setArray(newArr)//setArray will be a better name.
    }
    return(
       <>
        {
            arr.map((elements)=>{
                return <h1>{elements}</h1>
            })
        }   
        <button onClick={handleClick}>add</button>
       </>
    )
}
export default AppList
```

Comment: can't we do this adding element in old array and then passing that

Comment: No, because in the mind of React you didn't change anything so there is no need to rerender.